# What causes Twitter embedded videos to keep sending post requests with a 403 response code

Tags: twitter, embed

Embedded videos from twitter stopped working and keep sending a loop of post requests!!
[image: Twitter videos embed not working]

Answer (score 0):

It started to work again by itself, maybe it was just an issue from twitters part!